# Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Tags: email, spring-boot

I am getting the following error when setting up an email service with spring boot while trying to connect to round cube:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

This leads me to think roundcude is not using a SSL connection and I should not use port 143. Therefore I try and use port 25, but I get the following error when I do.

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

application.properties

```
#email setup
spring.mail.host = mail.email address.com
spring.mail.username = email address
spring.mail.password = my password

spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth= true
spring.mail.port = 25 or port 145
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class= javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback= false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable = true
```

Email service

```
@Component
public class EmailServiceImpl implements EmailService {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Override
    public void sendEmail(String toAddress, String fromAddress,
                          String subject, String body) {

        SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();

        simpleMailMessage.setFrom(fromAddress);
        simpleMailMessage.setTo(toAddress);
        simpleMailMessage.setSubject(subject);
        simpleMailMessage.setText(body);

        javaMailSender.send(simpleMailMessage);

    }
}
```

I looked at roundcube's documentation and apparently is uses port 143 so this is rather confusing. This making me think I am setting this up wrong.

I also tried gmail but since I have a two factor authentication I ran into more issue so I decided to use roundcube which is what I would rather use anyway.

Advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you're trying to connect to SMTP using non-secure ports. Usually secure ports would be 587 or 465.

This is the configuration that works for me to send e-mail using GMail:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=my-email@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=my-password
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class = javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout = 60000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout = 60000
```

Comment: I really think this is going to work. However I have two factor authentication. Looking more into it. I will accept your answer shortly. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: For gmail I had to turn on this flag: [https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)